# Need to re-enable an onmouseout that was disabled in onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onmouseout

I have searched here and on the Internet for code that can re-enable an `onMouseOut` that has been disabled in the `onClick` code. I have found things but nothing that works in my situation.

On the page there is a container div that holds two divs, one for an image and one for its corresponding text. Under the image are four links (1, 2, 3, 4) laid out in an unordered list. When the visitor rolls over the #2, the image needs to change to img2, the matching text div needs to go from "hidden" to "show". The `onMouseOut` resets the image and text to the original versions. The `onClick` changes the image/text to whatever # was clicked and then disables the `onMouseOut`.

Now I need a way to make the `onMOuseOut` work again the next time the visitor rolls over that #link. As I have it now, once the `onMouseOut` is disabled, it stays disabled until I reload the page.

Here is the code so far:

```
<head>
<script>
if (document.images) {
book1 = new Image
    book2 = new Image
    book3 = new Image
    book4 = new Image

book1.src = "/llb/assets/book1.jpg"
    book2.src = "/llb/assets/book2.jpg"
book3.src = "/llb/assets/book3.jpg"
    book4.src = "/llb/assets/book4.jpg"
}
function swapImage(thisImage,newImage) {
if (document.images) {
    document[thisImage].src = eval(newImage + ".src")
}
    

}
function show_visibility(IDS){
hide_visibility();
document.getElementById(IDS).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide_visibility(){
var sel = document.getElementById('bookleadin').getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
   <div id="books">
      <div id="bookimages">
        <img id="bookcover" name="bookcover" src="../llb/assets/book1.jpg" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book1'); show_visibility('bt1'); this.onmouseout=''" onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book1')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book2'); show_visibility('bt2'); this.onmouseout=''" onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book2')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="show_visibility('bt3'); swapImage('bookcover','book3')" onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book3')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book3')">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="show_visibility('bt4'); swapImage('bookcover','book4')" onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book4')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book4')">4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- end bookimages -->
      <div id="bookleadin">
        <div id="bt1" style="display:block;"><p>Writing starts with living...</p>
      </div>
        <div id="bt2" style="display:none;"><p>The air is silk...</p>
      </div>
        <div id="bt3" style="display:none;"><p>I lived in the woods...</p>
      </div>
        <div id="bt4" style="display:none;"><p>I tried to forget...</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end bookleadin -->
    <div class="spacer"></div>
   </div><!-- ends books -->
</div><!-- end content -->
```

list item #2 is the example I was testing with. I am still a Javascript beginner/intermediate, so any answer has to be simple enough for me to understand and apply to this project or complete so that I can just copy/paste it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag at `onclick` to be verified if it has been clicked if yes then do the swapping `onmouseout` else do nothing but do not do `this.onmouseout = ""`.

EDIT:

```
  <head>
<script>
    if(document.images) {
        book1 = new Image
        book2 = new Image
        book3 = new Image
        book4 = new Image

        book1.src = "/llb/assets/book1.jpg"
        book2.src = "/llb/assets/book2.jpg"
        book3.src = "/llb/assets/book3.jpg"
        book4.src = "/llb/assets/book4.jpg"
    }
    var swap_list = {}; // a list of swapped elements
    function swapImage(thisImage, newImage) {
        if(typeof swap_list[thisImage] == 'undefined' || swap_list[thisImage]=='')
            if(document.images) {
                document[thisImage].src = eval(newImage + ".src");
                swap_list[thisImage] = newImage;
            }
        else
            {
                swap_list[thisImage] = '';
                document[thisImage].src = "../llb/assets/book1.jpg";
            }
    }

    function show_visibility(IDS) {
        hide_visibility();
        document.getElementById(IDS).style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hide_visibility() {
        var sel = document.getElementById('bookleadin').getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
            sel[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="books">
            <div id="bookimages">
                <img id="bookcover" name="bookcover" src="../llb/assets/book1.jpg" />
                <ul>
                <li>
                        <a href="#" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book1'); show_visibility('bt1'); " onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book1')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')">1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book2'); show_visibility('bt2'); " onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book2')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')">2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick="show_visibility('bt3'); swapImage('bookcover','book3')" onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book3')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book3')">3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick="show_visibility('bt4'); swapImage('bookcover','book4')" onMouseOver="swapImage('bookcover','book4')" onMouseOut="swapImage('bookcover','book1')" onclick="swapImage('bookcover','book4')">4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end bookimages -->
        <div id="bookleadin">
            <div id="bt1" style="display:block;">
                <p>
                    Writing starts with living...
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="bt2" style="display:none;">
                <p>
                    The air is silk...
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="bt3" style="display:none;">
                <p>
                    I lived in the woods...
                </p>
                </div>
                <div id="bt4" style="display:none;">
                    <p>
                    I tried to forget...
                    </p>
            </div>
            </div><!-- end bookleadin -->
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div><!-- ends books -->
    </div><!-- end content -->
</body>
```

Comment: Let me rephrase it to see if I understand you. I would write a function that determines if the onClick has happened. If true, I would disable the onMouseOut, if false it would not touch the onMouseout so it would still happen when the cursor moved off the link and the original stuff would reappear.

Where would I call the verify function from? And what code would I use to disable the onMouseOut event, and how would I turn it back on for that link once a user hovers over or clicks a different link?

Comment: @ssliver1 You do not disable onmouseout, you just verifiy in it if the onclick happend, if it did then do nothing else do your code. Do you need some code or the pure logic of the algorithm is enough?

Comment: Maybe I do need some code. I am stuck trying to figure out when/where I would trigger a check for verifying the onclick. Each link has three events, mouseOver, mouseOut, and onCLick. If they click the link I need the mouseOut to do nothing. If they don't click, I need the mouseOut to complete an action. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ssliver1 I have reedited the post, sorry for the delay. Hope this is what you were looking.